# How to access Environment from service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a spring MVC application I want to access org.springframework.core.env.Environment variable from service layer so that I can call,

```
environment.getProperty()
```

My entire application configuration is based on annotations without using any XML.
I am configuring Environment bean as,

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config/deploy.properties")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;   
}
```

With above approach I can access environment from controllers but when I try to access it in a service class I get it NULL.
For example following service class,

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment; 
}
```

Any pointers?
Thanks.

Comment: How is UserService instantiated? Manually via new UserService() or via package scanning in application context XML?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework and post the log, then we can see whether Spring is creating the UserService bean or not.

Also can you post your code that is referencing UserService ?

Is UserService in a different context ?

Comment: The  UserService is being instantiated manually in the controller e.g. UserService userService = new UserService(). Yes, that must be the reason why it's not working. I will try by autowiring UserService and let you know. Meanwhile you can post your comments as answer and I will accept it after a quick check on my end. Thanks

Comment: Beside, if suppose I have no control over how UserService is instantiated is there a way to still access Environment in UserService?

Comment: Autowiring UserService in controller using @Autowired annotation works and that way I can access Environment in UserService class. Thank you Adam and PaulNUK for your help.

Comment: just to share the other way, using https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware.html annotation on Spring beans.